# How to move a range of element in a list to the front of an element also in the same list?

Tags: c++, list

I want to move a range of element in a list to the front of an element also in the same list. I'm trying to use

```
list.splice(const_iterator pos, list &other, const_iterator first, const_iterator last)
```

to implement this.

This is my code:

```cpp
list<int> ls{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

// try to move [6, 9] to the front of 5
auto pos = find(ls.cbegin(), ls.cend(), 5), first = ++pos;
ls.splice(pos, ls, first, ls.end());
```

cppreference says:

> Transfers the elements in the range [first, last) from other into *this. The elements are inserted before the element pointed to by pos. The behavior is undefined if pos is an iterator in the range [first,last).

Actually pos != first, but this causes a infinite loop. What causes this to happen, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in actually pos != first

No. Given `first = ++pos`, `pos` is incremented and assigned to `first`. They are equivalent, and `pos` is in the range [first,last).

I think you want `first = std::next(pos);`.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TvI9ZH6HuzdIFSFe)

Comment: I have found the reason of this problem just now, but thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a bit hidden. The problem lies in `first = ++pos`. This leads to `first == pos`, making the `splice` become UB

Solution:

```cpp
auto pos = find(ls.cbegin(), ls.cend(), 5), first = pos;
ls.splice(pos, ls, ++first, ls.end());
```